# Bone "Mirror names" function makes bones parented

Tags: armature, bones, parent

I wanted to ask if this is a normal behavior. SO the problem is I am creating a simple right leg rig with three bones and parent them to the pelvis. Then I mirror it to the left leg. And I have noticed that when I leave the checkbox "Mirror names" unchecked - everything works as usual. But when I want to mirror names(Thigh.l - Thigh.r) - the function works but causes some weird dependence between the bones - they rotate together if I try to rotate any one of them as if their rotation becomes linked. If I rename them - everything works as it should, but if I return to the Blender naming convention Name.l, Name.left - the glitch returns. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what operation do you do to mirror? where is the "mirror names" option? I personally use header menu Armature > Symmetrize when I want to symmetrize

Comment: I use simple mirror "command" because Symmetrize doesn't work properly for me for some reason. With the necessary bone chain selected I press Duplicate-Ctrl+M and there's the  "Mirror names" checkbox. That's where trouble happens

Comment: there should be no problem with symmetrize, I've forgotten the old way of mirroring the armature so I guess someone will help you better than me  :/

Comment: maybe share your file (version with the problem happening)

Comment: The file is a total clutter. Maybe instead you could check the same procedure that I did? I mean mirror bones the Ctrl+M way with the checkbox "Mirror names" checked? And if you don't have the same problem - I will just know that I screwed up somewhere and it's not Blender.

Comment: just keep the armature and share it  ;)   I've tried with ctrl M with Flipped Names and it works on my computer

Comment: Here. Check if you can download it pls https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TwbOOKu5aDSijXomKYpUL2Wah9-GUTj6

Comment: it looks like it works fine, what bone are you talking about?

Comment: I tried that with the leg bones. I ended up naming the right part differently - Thigh.p, Shin.p instead of Thigh.r and Shin.r - otherwise that glitch appeared - the bones were starting to rotate together as if parented.

Comment: if I call them Thigh.r and Shin.r it looks like it works normally, so as I asked please send the armature with the problem

Comment: Here. I haven't used the service before (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6434/)

Comment: I still don't see any problem + it's the same version as before, i.e. it has the names Thigh.p, Shin.p

Comment: I don't know - perhaps something's wrong locally, just can't fathom what it could be. Thank you anyway. Will keep on digging

Comment: no but please share the file with the problem, you did not

Comment: Here. I have removed all IK's - just the skeleton with those faulty legs [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6435" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6435/)

Comment: in the N panel > Tool > You've enabled the X-Axis Mirror option, is it the problem you're talking about?

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks man. IDK how it happened - perhaps yet another long forgotten shortcut. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In the 3D View *N* panel, deactivate the *X-Axis Mirror* option, it makes the opposite bone move when you move a bone.

[image]